# How to delete selected row from database with php,js?

Tags: javascript, php

On a php page I will show the records of table. Then I want to delete the selected rows by checkboxes by clicking the button. How do I do that?

Comment: Render your table with ids (coming from the database). If you select the row and hit the delete button, send this information via AJAX to your backend. From there you simply make a call do the database to delete the given record. Watch out for SQL injections tho!

Comment: You can find the ids of the `checked` rows and send all the `ids` to the back-end(php) and using `Delete from `TABLENAME`` query, you can delete them!

Comment: have you tried any method if post your code

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make with POST method also
Just set the id of row (retreive from database) as value of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=<?php echo $id;?> " >
```

and then hit the DELETE button.

On POST page you will get the ID of checked record.

Get all ID and combine all ID with implode function

```
$chkIds = $_POST["chk"];    
$allIds = implode("','",$chkIds);
```

run the SQL query like :-

```
"DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN ('$allIds')"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass your selected data id to your server;

FE: ajax -> send data to SERVER:php -> DATABAST:mysql run sql `delete from  table where xxx`

So you should try learn about `ajax` and `php pdo`